# Set persistent variable in a class method from another page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and I understand that the ASP.NET page only lives until the request is being served. And then it dies. I have a class in a website that has a row like this:

```
 command.CommandText = "select TOP 50 * from FeederEntry WHERE IsDeleted = 0 ORDER BY PubDate DESC";
```

I need to control the TOP 50, which in some situation may require to be changed to xx or xxx.
So I was thinking to change that line of code like this:

```
command.CommandText = "select TOP " + "string " + "* from FeederEntry WHERE IsDeleted = 0 ORDER BY PubDate DESC";
```

My problem is that I do not know how to set the "variable" from code behind of another page and to make it persistent. I mean to hold the value even if there are not Sessions active.
Is that possible in asp.net and how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to share across session store it in `Database/Application variable`

Comment: @Murali, so basically write the variable to the db from code behind of a page and read it back in the class method. Nice, thanks you a lot.

Comment: You can use `Application["key"]=anyValue or static variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static variable which is appropriate only in few cases, this might be one.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static int SELECT_TOP_ROWCOUNT = 50;
}
```

Then you could parametrize the top clause in this way:

```
command.CommandText = "select TOP (@TOP) * from FeederEntry WHERE IsDeleted = 0 ORDER BY PubDate DESC";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOP", GlobalVariables.SELECT_TOP_ROWCOUNT);
```

Instead you can also use the HTTP-Cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly, I still would have the problem to assign the value to the variable from a page textbox and make it persistent.

Comment: @FeliceM: Why? `Static` does not mean `readonly`. Just set it: `GlobalVariables.SELECT_TOP_ROWCOUNT = 100;`.

Comment: May be I was not clear in my question, sorry for that. I have a textbox in a page "configure.aspx" I wont to write in there the number xx. I need that number to be persistent even when I logout. This feature will be used by users accessing the website not the code.

Comment: @FeliceM: Then you need to persist it in a database or in the web.config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. However I learned something to solve another problem from your answer.